# Assert Values After Exception Happened with Mokito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to test a service by using Mockito that made a remote call to external API.
If the call is fails, I should do some other operations.
SO I mock the external remote call, and I use the following:

```
public class Service {

    private Remotecall remotecall;

    public void method1() {
        try {
            remotecall.callAPI();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logMessage("Important Log message"); // goes to another method to add somedata!
        }
    }
}

public class Remotecall {

    public void callAPI() {
        try {

            callExternalAPI();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GenericException("some message");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use this way:

```
when(remotecall.callAPI()).thenThrow(Exception.class);
AssertTrue(logmessage);
```

The test return null point exception!

How can I write a test in java using Mockito to test the value in the logMessage() method.
Is it right to mock the remotecall class and inject callAPI()?

Comment: Please, show your test class code.

Comment: when(remotecall.callAPI()).thenThrow(Exception.class); AssertTrue(logmessage);

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace to see where exactly the null pointer exception is trown?

Comment: As far as I can see, the code in your test should not compile. `remotecall.callAPI()` appears to return `void`, and you can't call a method returning `void` in a call to `when()`. You can write `doThrow(Exception.class).when(remotecall).callAPI();` instead. I can't say how you could test the value passed to the `logMessage` method, because you haven't shared with us how this method is defined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would not be able to simulate the real scenario because it is confidential work. But I can assure you that what you have written was really helpful, helping me figuring out the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method callAPI() takes no arguments so your 'when' statement should be

```
when(remotecall.callAPI()).thenThrow(Exception.class);
```

Comment: yes but the question mainly after throwing exception and putting that in when(), how can I assert the value in catch block?